# What use does Gardevoir have?

Tags: super-smash-bros-brawl

When you throw a Pokeball and Gardevoir appears, she appears to have a force-field around her. However, it doesn't seem to do anything. Does Gardevoir have any use?

Comment: I know this isn't an answer but I once got a Gardevoir and my opponent got a Kyogre and the Kyogre's water reflected and pushed my opponent off the stage and it was so satisfying.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The field surrounding [Gardevoir](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Gardevoir) is a giant reflection bubble, reflecting and doubling the damage of any projectile that opponents try to toss inside or use while inside. It doesn't attack opponents directly, but you can feel free to camp nearby and shoot your own projectiles outwards while being safe from most anything that doesn't come up and punch you in the face.